# Trouble running craft with docker

Tags: php, setup, docker

I'm trying to set up craft to run with the docker images provided [here](https://github.com/craftcms/docker). When I run `docker-compose build`, it gets through a few lines in the Dockerfile and then stops with an `invalid reference error` after these three lines:

> ARG PHP_VERSION 
> ARG PROJECT_TYPE 
> FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-${PROJECT_TYPE}-alpine

I do have php installed, but somehow the arguments aren't getting through to docker correctly. Has anyone gotten the docker images from that repo set up/integrated properly?

I'm no docker wizard so apologies if this is some really simple docker thing.

Comment: [Nitro 2](https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/2.x/) is on Docker, is it an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using the [nitro tutorial](https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/environment/stack.html#why-nitro) instead. Thanks @Oli!